# gnuplot: Plotting matrix with the colors I want

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a matrix with colors with gnuplot, and I'm using the following code:

```
set terminal png
set output "Matrix.png"
set title "Matrix"
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
plot "Lattice.txt" matrix with image
```

Lattice.txt can be filled with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

The code as it works for the most part, but if in lattice.txt there are only 0 and 1, it will assign the black color to 0. If I have 1, 2 and 3 in Lattice.txt, it will assign the black color to 1.

How can I choose a color for each number so it always outputs, for example, black when there is a 0, red when there is a 1, blue when there is a 2?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set palette define (0 "black", 0 "black", 1 "red", 1 "red", 2 "blue", 2 "blue", 3 "orange", 3 "orange", 4 "gold", 4 "gold", 5 "green", 5 "green")
set cbrange [0:5]
```

[modified to show that for this case a simpler palette definition is OK]

```
set palette define (0 "black", 1 "red", 2 "blue", 3 "orange", 4 "gold", 5 "green")
set cbrange [0:5]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and it works perfectly, thanks! But I'm wondering why we need to define the colors two times?

Comment: I just tested, and for this example I think you only need one entry per color.  In general the command wants ranges, as in x->y is green y->z is blue, and so on.  But since you only have integer values, the color that would have gone to intermediate fractional values is not relevant.